# Hint for evaluating an integral $\int \frac{x(a-x^{2})}{((a-x^{2})^{2}-bx^{2})^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I <s>solve</s> evaluate the following integral?

$$\int \frac{x(a-x^{2})}{\Big((a-x^{2})^{2}-bx^{2}\Big)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the positive real constants.

Comment: So what is the integral missing that would make it easy to solve?

Comment: The phrase "where $f$ and $g$ are the differentiable real functions of $x$ makes no sense since the letters $f$ and $g$ do not appear anywhere in the expression above them. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Beginning from the integral

$$I=\int \frac{x(a-x^{2})}{\left((a-x^{2})^{2}-bx^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\text dx$$

it is clear that a term $-bx\over 2\sqrt{((a-x^2)^2-bx^2)^3}$ is all that is missing in order to have

$$I+J=\int \frac{x(a-x^{2})-\frac b2x}{\sqrt{\left((a-x^{2})^{2}-bx^{2}\right)^3}}\text dx=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{(a-x^{2})^{2}-bx^{2}}}+\mathcal C$$

Adding and subtracting this part allows us to instead evaluate

$$J=\int{-bx\over 2\sqrt{((a-x^2)^2-bx^2)^3}}\text dx$$

Trying a substitution first, use $x^2=y,2x\text dx=\text dy$:

$$J=\int{-b\over 4\sqrt{((a-y)^2-by)^3}}\text dy$$

With just a bit more algebra, we get

$$(a-y)^2-by=a^2-2ay+y^2-by=\left(y-a-\frac b2\right)^2-\frac {b^2}4-ab$$

and the resulting integral should be susceptible to standard methods.  Further hint in this direction:

$$J=\int{-b\over 4\sqrt{\left(\left(y-a-\frac b2\right)^2-\frac {b^2}4-ab\right)^3}}\text dy\\
y-a-\frac b2=\sqrt{\frac{b^2}4+ab}\cosh u\\
\text dy=\sqrt{\frac{b^2}4+ab}\sinh u\text du\\
J=-\frac b4\sqrt{\frac{b^2}4+ab}\int \frac{\sinh u}{\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{b^2}4+ab\right)\cosh^2 u-\left(\frac{b^2}4+ab\right)\right)^3}}\text du\\
=-\frac 1{b+4a}\int \frac{1}{\sinh^2 u}\text du$$

From here, Wikipedia can give a straightforward answer, or more algebraic contortions are possible as well.

Edit:

It is worth mentioning that an initial substitution $y=a-x^2,\text dy =-2x\text dx$ leads to $$-\frac 12\int \frac y{\sqrt{(y^2-ab-by)^3}}\text dy$$ which is clearly a much easier integral to $\text{tackle}^*$.

${}^*$ Except for that pesky $-b$ constant that crops up when we try to use a substitution...

Comment: Notice  we have $$[(a-y)^{2}-by]^{\frac{3}{2}} = [(y-a-\frac b2)^2-\frac {b^2}4 - ab]^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: @user: good point, thank you.

Comment: If $u= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(y-a-\frac b2\right)^2-\frac {b^2}4-ab}}$, then $$du = \dfrac{(y-a-\frac{b}{2}) dy}{[(y-a-\frac b2)^2-\frac {b^2}4 - ab]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$, now how can one solve this integral? may you explain in more details?

Comment: @user: with that substitution, you peel away the exponent of $3$, and get a new integral of the form $$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}+ab+\frac {b^2}4}\text du$$.

Comment: @user: eventually you get to the point of reaching out to trigonometry or other transcendental functions, as I point out in my extra hint.  The primary reason for this is that we don't have a simple $$\int\frac{f'}{f^q}\text df$$

Comment: @user: is there something missing that would make an acceptable answer to your question?

Comment: Of course not. it is complete, without missing something.